# Javascript/jQuery: Check if two values are equal regardless of data type?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am have an if condition where I need to check  if A has the same value as B irrespective of data type, like

```
if (A == B) {
   //body of if statement
}
```

but the server check in validation will reject if `==` is present. It will ask to change that to `===` (but I can't change this).

How I can achieve this, where the possible values and types of `A` & `B` are

```
String, Number, null, '', undefined, NaN
```

Looks simple but may just be a logic error... :)

Comment: I think you could hack it into `if ( A.toString() === B.toString() ) { ... }`

Comment: @Aziz That will throw error in **some** cases

Comment: *"but my Server check in validation will reject if "==" present it will ask to change "===".(I can't change)"* Well, get whoever *can* change it to change it. Sometimes you want `==`.

Comment: Are you **quite** sure you want to compare a string to a boolean, and are you **quite** sure you know how `==` does that?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I can't change software policies.

Comment: @JqueryRock So there is probably good reason you cannot use `==`. What is your real use case?

Comment: @A.Wolff: Our Software Architectures thinking they are too smart and they did like that.

Comment: @JqueryRock You didn't answer previous question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fundamentally, there are valid use cases for `==` and so I would suggest finding whoever *can* change that rule and having them do so.

In the absense of that, you can write yourself a function that does what `==` does, which is called the [abstract equality comparison algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-abstract-equality-comparison), and then use that function instead of `==`:

> The comparison x == y, where x and y are values, produces true or false. Such a comparison is performed as follows:
>
> 1. If [Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values)(x) is the same as [Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values)(y), then
>
>    1. Return the result of performing [Strict Equality Comparison](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-strict-equality-comparison) x === y.
> 2. If x is null and y is undefined, return true.
> 3. If x is undefined and y is null, return true.
> 4. If [Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values)(x) is Number and [Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values)(y) is String, return the result of the comparison x == [ToNumber](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-tonumber)(y).
> 5. If [Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values)(x) is String and [Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values)(y) is Number, return the result of the comparison [ToNumber](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-tonumber)(x) == y.
> 6. If [Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values)(x) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison [ToNumber](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-tonumber)(x) == y.
> 7. If [Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values)(y) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison x == [ToNumber](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-tonumber)(y).
> 8. If [Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values)(x) is either String, Number, or Symbol and [Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values)(y) is Object, return the result of the comparison x == [ToPrimitive](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-toprimitive)(y).
> 9. If [Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values)(x) is Object and [Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values)(y) is either String, Number, or Symbol, return the result of the comparison [ToPrimitive](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-toprimitive)(x) == y.
> 10. Return false.

The exact implementation of every abstract operation used above is clearly defined in the spec.

Comment: I think the problem is **that** you need a workaround! @JqueryRock

Comment: @JqueryRock: The second paragraph starts the workaround.

Answer (score -2):

I found it,(Workaround)

```
 A = A ? A.toString() : A;
 B = B ? B.toString() : B;
 if(A === B){
  //Rock it
 }
```

Comment: Well `"0" == 0` is `true` but your 'workaround' returns `false`... You should test it before posting it as answer